# The omission of "le"

Tags: gramática, objetos-indirectos

En frases como… "Le doy algo a alguien..." ¿Es siempre necesario expresar "le", o es suficiente usar "a alguien"?

Creí que siempre era necesario expresar el complemento indirecto, ya que muchos hispanohablantes no lo usan.

Answer (score 2):

Es necesario, si quieres que la frase suene "natural" en el ejemplo:

> Le doy mi camisa a Nancy

Si omites [Le] entonces se pierde el sentido de la frase, suena "robótico" o no "natural":

> Doy mi camisa a Nancy

Comment: Es cierto: suena extraño. Parece que falta algo...